# Launch an executable from the same dir as a Qt app when white spaces in path

Tags: c++, qt, executable, qprocess

I would like to launch an executable when pushing a button in my Qt app.
This `.exe` is always located in the same directory as the Qt app itself.

Sometimes there are white spaces in the path to this directory. This seems to prevent the `.exe` from starting.

Here is my code (that doesn't seem to work):

```
QString path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath ();
path.append("/executable.exe");

QProcess process;
process.execute(path);
```

I don't know if it is possible to start the `.exe` without showing a command prompt first.
When the `.exe` is running I have to close the Qt app, while the `.exe` keeps running.

Comment: You meant process.execute(path), right?

Comment: Yes, I changed the post.

Comment: @OO-SKY: I wonder what else is different in the post than it is in your code...

Comment: @PlasmaHH : That is exactly my code. But I think that my tests with **system(path)** were failing due to the white space in the path. **process.execute(path)** isn't working even without white spaces.

Comment: use `QProcess::startDetached()` to spawn new process, that wouldn't close when spawning application quits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`execute(QString)` uses a single string for both executable path and arguments. Without proper quoting, `C:\A path with spaces\foo.exe` will be interpreted as `c:\A` as executable and `path`, `with` `spaces\foo.exe` as arguments.

To avoid this, use the overload `execute(QString, QStringList)` that takes the arguments as separate string list, even if you don't want to pass arguments at all:

```
QProcess::execute(path, QStringList());
```

This does the right thing and doesn't require any quoting from your side.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer to the white spaces problem. The problem that I face now, is that this works with every app except with my executable (which is an NSIS installer). Could this be due to the necessary administrator rights?